# Writing a HashMap to a text file Android studio

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have tried to use serialisation to write my HashMap into a text file but it just doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I'm using it wrong
my Hashmap :
    HashMap lettersAvailable = new HashMap();
and my code I use for serialisation

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/FenceInformation.ser");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            Map lettersAvailable = (Map)objectInputStream.readObject();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hashmap reloaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException | ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("YourInfomration.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(lettersAvailable);
            oos.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


   }
```

In the onResume method it says lettersAvailable variable is never used at Maps lettersAvailable

Is there not another way to do this?

Comment: Would you mind giving the error displayed?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error. Just doesn't make the file, either that or I'm looking to find it in the wrong place. In onResume it tells me that my lettersAvailable which is my hashMap is never used.